# Emacs Python-Mode: Sending statements to a subprocess does not lead to REPL-style evaluation

Tags: python, emacs

After selecting `1 + 1` and issuing *python-send-region*, my subprocess buffer shows no results. I have to evaluate `print 1 + 1`, instead.

How can I force the python-send-* commands to print the value of the respective statements rather than echoing their stdout?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need print; use print.

emacs is launching a python process and getting text from its standard output, not a python value.

Comment: Thanks. Is there something like SLIME or Inf-Ruby for Python?